# A prophet denies his existence

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, anagram

What is my anagram - A prophet denies his existence?

Clue:

> (1, 3, 4)

Comment: cryptic clues usually also have an enumeration too.

Comment: Are you sure this is a cryptic clue? A cryptic crossword clue has both a *straight definition* (as you might see in American crosswords), and *wordplay* that leads you to the solution separately.

Comment: @ Deusovi - I'd say it comes close to what you describe but the 'straight' definition would be pretty much impossible to fathom unless you first get the cryptic part. Therefore I've changed the tag.

Comment: @Sid - True. I was planning to add this at a later date if no-one solves it.

Comment: Does the anagram include "what is my anagram?" (question mark as well)?

Comment: @ S. M. - Apologies to all. I misplaced the question mark. I have rewritten the clue.

Comment: Still, my question was if "what is my anagram" is included in the anagram itself (if it's part of the puzzle to *not* know that then nevermind, my bad).

Comment: The straight answer is that it is not true that the entire phrase "*what is my anagram*" is included in the anagram.

Comment: There are *lots* of anagrams of "a prophet denies his existence". How are we supposed to know which specific one you're referring to? In general, any anagram over twelve letters has too many possibilities to pick out the "correct" one unless it's by guessing.

Comment: It may be that US crosswords operate differently from UK ones. In British ones a question mark usually indicates a paraphrase.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: @ Instantsoup - Are you suggesting I'm being smug? I thought I was just doing my best to set a puzzle ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I WAS MYTH ("what is my" anagram)

Answer (score 1):

> a sheep he is risen except i dont

Answer (score 0):

> I Expect he reasoned pithiness?

Comment: Not what I'm looking for! (and not on the right track) I'll see if I can add another constraint.

Comment: I think I may have misplaced the question mark - I've rewritten - apologies.